# Isolated scope breaks attrs.$observe

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have my nice removeDialog directive as a result of this question:

[Updating attrs value inside directive - how to do it in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916891/updating-attrs-value-inside-directive-how-to-do-it-in-angularjs)

And now I started playing with isoleted scope. The first thing I've noticed is that adding isolated scope broke attrs.$observe. I do not receive notifications when **trigger** is changed.

```
homesApp.directive("removeDialog", function ($parse) {
    return {
        scope: {

        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            angular.element(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.cancelRemove();
                });
            });
            attrs.$observe('trigger', function (newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    angular.element(element).modal('show');
                } else {
                    angular.element(element).modal('hide');
                }
            });
        },
        controller: 'DeleteController'
    };
});
```

Could you elaborate why?

Comment: Why don't you just try `scope: true` instead of `scope: {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `trigger` is not bound to the outer scope anymore. You need to declare it in your isolate scope:

```
scope: {
    trigger: '='
}
```

This will bind `scope.trigger` to the actual expression that you define on the element in which the directive is applied.

This way, `attrs.$observe('trigger', function (newValue) {...}` should change to

```
scope.$watch('trigger', function (newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                angular.element(element).modal('show');
            } else {
                angular.element(element).modal('hide');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. However one more question: provided that when I use isolated scope, I bind scope.trigger to ACTUAL EXPRESSION (which is expression without {{}}, then what is happening with trigger when I do not use isolated scope and access it with attrs (and expression is with {{}}) ?

Comment: @dragonfly I don't have a clear idea of could happen. Don't you have an actual example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I mean: when working with attrs.$observe('trigger',...) my directive had trigger={{expression}}, whereas when using isolated scope I had to change it to trigger=expression. And I don't get why both methods require or not {{}}.

Comment: @dragonfly I get your confusion. The angularjs authors should be more explicit when naming the APIs that deal with interpolation (such as `attrs.$observe`), because this is such an obstacle in understanding directives as a whole -- an already difficult subject. But this comment box is too small for discussing all this, and I hope I had helped you! Good luck.